# Unexpected array index out of bounds exception

Tags: java, exception

On the line with the "here" comment I get an index out of bounds error for some input data. It does not always occur. It does not occur when the program is run on my machine, even. It occurs when a project teammate runs the project on his laptop.

I know there's output from the exception regarding the actual index, but for reasons I don't have that information right now. I might be able to update with the full exception soon.

```
public int getDistance(int[] arrayA, int[] arrayB) {
    int[][] array = new int[arrayA.length][arrayB.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++)
        array[i][0] = i;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayB.length; i++)
        array[0][i] = i; // Here
```

I cut the method off here as the remainder shouldn't be relevant.

As you can see I create a two dimensional array from two single dimensional arrays (arrayA and arrayB) and the width and height of that array equals the length of the two single dimensional arrays. Then I set the "leftmost" column to incrementing numbers and the "uppermost" row to incrementing numnbers.

If you need more code, I can post it.

Comment: It's obvious that whatever makes up `array` does not have `[0][i]` valid positon. It will tell you in the exception which one is wrong. (It will actually tell you how much you overflowed)

Comment: "*I know there's output from the exception regarding the actual index, but for reasons I don't have that information right now.*" => well that contains your answer and should be your first step in trouble shooting your problem...

Comment: The only situation that I can think of is if one of the arrays is empty (i.e. there is no `0` index).

Comment: Can you tell me both array length that you are passing to getDistance?

Comment: It worked! To be honest I didn't even consider that problem at all seeing that this was a project assignment and we specified I would never be sent zero length lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When at least one of the array's lenght is 0 then it throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Try for example:

```
int[] arrayA = new int[4];
int[] arrayB = new int[0];

getDistance(arrayA, arrayB);
```

Comment: Thank you for that :P. I was not even considering the possibility that an input array would turn out to be of size zero. But I realize now there's a small chance it is, given a particular input in the outer method.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that the exception occurs when one of the lists is of length 0, ie. lets say arrayA is the problem and has length=0, you then create array [0][arrayB.length] and when you then try to call array[0][i] it cant access element 0 and throws an OutofBoundsException